# Stuck at "Kill aliens" in "All Hands On Deck"

Tags: technical-issues, saints-row-iv

While playing through The Kinzie Gambit's second half, All Hands on Deck, I get reproducibly stuck at the section where you board the enemy ship and are told to clear up a bunch of enemies ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=er7-zvrWxlE#t=178)).

How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the two free DLCs you can get for Saints Row 4 on Steam.

1. Sigh and close the game. Restarting from a checkpoint or through the whole mission won't help.
2. Locate Saints Row 4 in your Steam library and right click, then click Properties.
3. Head to the DLC tab and uncheck "Saints Row IV - Reverse Cosplay Pack" and "Saints Row IV - Thank You Pack", [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW2Ay.png). If you have more DLCs than this, it's probably better to remove them all at this stage and re-add them later.
4. For good measure, switching to Local Files tab and verifying  the integrity of the local cache can't hurt.
5. Launch the game again. [The game will warn you about your successful removal of DLCs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7zvt.jpg)
6. Play through the entirety of Kinzie Gambit and All Hands on Deck again. Sigh.

Comment: +1 for "Sigh and close the game".  Does not work without the sigh.

Comment: @Batophobia You will find that the sighing comes naturally to you when it dawns on you that you've lost the last 10 minutes of progress.